# Run Methods inside a thread synchronously C# .net core

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am starting a background thread in my .net core controller like this

```
var t = new System.Threading.Thread(() => LongRunningTask()) 
                                         { IsBackground = true };
t.Start();
```

Then My long running method is something similar to this

```
public void LongRunningTask(){
    
    A();
    B();
    C();
 }
```

However sometimes I noticed method C executed before the end of method A.
Are there any way to make these A B C methods executed each after the other.

Or else are there ant better approach to run this long-running tasks without user to wait until all these finishes?

Comment: How do you notice this?

Comment: Unless A,B,C are asynchronous, there is no way C could start executing before A finishes.

Comment: Please provide definitions of methods `A`, `B` and `C`.

Comment: *I am starting a background thread in my .net core controller like this* -- well, there's problem 1. You don't run threads from a controller. ASP.NET Core gives you wonderful tools to allow you to do things in the background without resorting to antiquated patterns such as `Thread`. Look up `IHostedService` or `BackgroundService`.

Answer (score -1):

They are *started* one after another on the same thread so `A` will always finish before `B` starts assuming `A` is synchronous and doesn't for example include any `await` statements that will cause it to return before you consider it to be finished.

If the methods are asynchronous, they should return a `Task` and you should await them, e.g.:

```
var t = new System.Threading.Thread(async () => await LongRunningTask())
{ IsBackground = true };
t.Start();

async Task LongRunningTask()
{
    await A();
    await B();
    await C();
}
```